# HOW TO ADD JCHECKBOX TO A JCOMBOBOX

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, combobox

I need to do a menu with checkboxes inside, I cant do it! I checked all the java api documentation and dont exist examples. Help...

```
   JComboBox<JCheckBox> cb = new JComboBox<JCheckBox>();

   cb.add(cbEasy = new JCheckBox("EASY", false));
   cb.add(cbDifficult = new JCheckBox("DIFFICULT", false));
```

In the interface its empty the combobox...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a menu with checkboxes, it's better to use a JMenu with JCheckBoxMenuItems, or rather JRadioMenuItems if the choices are mutually exclusives:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Difficulty");
JRadioButtonMenuItem item1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Easy");
JRadioButtonMenuItem item2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Normal");
JRadioButtonMenuItem item3 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Hard");

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(item1);
group.add(item2);
group.add(item3);

menu.add(item1);
menu.add(item2);
menu.add(item3);
```